# Create page views using CSS

Tags: html, css

I recently visited the website: [**CSS Menu Samples**](http://www.cssmenusamples.com/)

I liked their pages method which is located on the bottom:

[image: **Pages**]

I have added what I found so far but it's not coming out correctly (especially in IE)

**FireFox**:

[image: FireFox]

**IE**:

[image: IE]

Here's my JSFiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h82Nt/)

HTML:

```
<div class="navmeta">
    <div class='wp-pagenavi'>
        <span class='pages'>Page 1 of 48</span><span class='current'>1</span><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/2' class='page larger'>2</a><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/3' class='page larger'>3</a><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/4' class='page larger'>4</a><a href="http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/2" class="nextpostslink">&raquo;</a><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/10' class='larger page'>10</a><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/20' class='larger page'>20</a><span class='extend'>...</span><a href='http://www.cssmenusamples.com/page/48' class='last'>Last &raquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wp-pagenavi{
    margin-left:auto !important;
    margin-right:auto !important;
}
.navmeta {
    clear:both;
    margin-top:30px;
    top:30px;
    padding:30px 0;
    padding-right:180px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-bottom:40px;


}
.wp-pagenavi a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/navi.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height:25px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.navmeta .current {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.wp-pagenavi {
    padding: 10px 20px 10 !important;
    display:block !important;
    clear:both !important;
}
.wp-pagenavi a ,.wp-pagenavi span.pages, .wp-pagenavi span.extend {
        color:#333333 !important;
        text-shadow:0px 1px #F6F6F6 !important;
        padding:6px 9px 6px 9px !important;
        border:solid 1px #B6B6B6 !important;
        box-shadow:0px 1px #EFEFEF !important;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px #EFEFEF !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px #EFEFEF !important;
        background:#E6E6E6 !important;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#FFFFFF 1px,#F3F3F3 1px,#E6E6E6) !important;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,color-stop(0.02,#FFFFFF),color-stop(0.02,#F3F3F3),color-stop(1,#E6E6E6)) !important;
        font-size:12px !important;
        margin-right:3px !important;
        text-decoration:none !important;
}   
.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
        color:#fff !important;
        text-shadow:0px 1px #4E802C !important;
        border-color:#478223 !important;
        background:#599F2F !important;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9FE355 1px,#79BF4A 1px,#599F2F) !important;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,color-stop(0.02,#9FE355),color-stop(0.02,#79BF4A),color-stop(1,#599F2F)) !important;
        color:#FFFFFF !important;
        box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;

}
 .wp-pagenavi span.current{
        padding:6px 9px 6px 9px !important;
        border:solid 1px #DCDCDC !important;
        color:#fff !important;
        box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
        margin-right:3px !important;
        text-shadow:0px 1px #4E802C !important;
        border-color:#478223 !important;
        background:#599F2F !important;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9FE355 1px,#79BF4A 1px,#599F2F) !important;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,color-stop(0.02,#9FE355),color-stop(0.02,#79BF4A),color-stop(1,#599F2F)) !important;
}
```

Comment: your "JDfiddle"? It is "JSfiddle"... maybe you should edit that ;)

Comment: ;) nice job, I hope you figure this out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/h82Nt/2/

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly in FF but in IE is still the same issue

Comment: @SiKni8  Which version of IE are you using?
I don't see any problems in my IE.

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support `box-shadow`, `text-shadow` and `background` with `gradient` — here's why it is not working.

Comment: IE Version 8 and I know I should upgrade but I was trying to see if it's compatible with older version.

Comment: Is there an alternative for IE < 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for IE because you have the prefixes for -moz- and -webkit- but you don't have code to support IE. 
if you go to [this site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and choose your gradient it will give you all the code including the code for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is redundant. You can achieve this with one single class almost.

!important everywhere is useless and should not be used if you do not understand why you need them. :)

To set every thing on the same line: use vertical-align: *for inline-element it is fine*.

give size with line-height and a bit of padding, text will do the rest.

For IE and old browser , declare a `background-color` ,and for gradients, declare them as `background-image`.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7YHE/

```
    .navmeta {
    margin:40px auto;
    display:table;
}
.page.current {
    background: url(images/navi.gif) no-repeat center center;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:solid 1px #DCDCDC;
    box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7;
    background-color:#599F2F;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #9FE355 1px, #79BF4A 1px, #599F2F) !important;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.02, #9FE355), color-stop(0.02, #79BF4A), color-stop(1, #599F2F));
    background:linear-gradient(top, #9FE355 1px, #79BF4A 1px, #599F2F);
    border-color:#478223;
}
.page {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:#333333;
    text-shadow:0px 1px #F6F6F6;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border:solid 1px #B6B6B6;
    box-shadow:0px 1px #EFEFEF;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.02, #FFFFFF), color-stop(0.02, #F3F3F3), color-stop(1, #E6E6E6));
    background:linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 1px, #F3F3F3 1px, #E6E6E6);
    font-size:12px;
    margin-right:3px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.page:hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0px 1px #4E802C;
    border-color:#478223;
    background:#599F2F;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #9FE355 1px, #79BF4A 1px, #599F2F) !important;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.02, #9FE355), color-stop(0.02, #79BF4A), color-stop(1, #599F2F));
    box-shadow:0px 1px #E7E7E7 !important;
}
```